# How to rank variables in SAS by summarising another variable

Tags: sas, rank

For example:

```
Groupvar    Value
A           5
A           1
B           0
B           9
B           8 
C           2
C           2
```

I want to rank by the Groupvar summarising on Value. So in this example sum(A) = 6, sum(B) = 17, sum(C) = 4. So Rank 1 = B, rank 2 = A, rank 3 = 6.

Ideal output:

```
Groupvar    Value    Rank
A           5         2
A           1         2
B           0         1
B           9         1
B           8         1
C           2         3
C           2         3
```

Any ideas how this can be done? I can create a proc summary > then rank> then merge the rank back on. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the variable created by the LEVELS options plus ORDER=FREQ. For example.

```
data have;
   input Groupvar:$1. Value;
   cards;
A           5
A           1
B           0
B           9
B           8 
C           2
C           2
;;;;
   run;
proc summary nway order=freq missing;
   class groupvar;
   freq value;
   output out=test(drop=_type_ index=(groupvar)) / levels;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   merge have test;
   by groupvar;
   run;
proc print; 
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it at one `proc sql`:

```
data test1;
    Ord + 1;
    input Groupvar$ Value;
    cards;
    A 5
    A 1
    B 0
    B 9
    B 8
    C 2
    C 2
    ;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    create table Test2 as 
    select Groupvar, sum(Value) as Sum
    from Test1
    group by Groupvar
    order by Sum
    ;

    create table Test3 as 
    select a.*, b.Sum, b.Rank
    from Test1 as a
    left join (
        select a.*, monotonic() as Rank
        from Test2 as a
    ) as b
    on a.Groupvar = b.Groupvar
    order by Ord
    ;
quit;
```